# ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) ->dtype('<U21')

Tags: string, repeat, assign

I'm trying to assign new columns to DataFrame,
The dataframe that I wanted to make is like this

|  | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | 2 | B:99 |
| row2 | 5 | B:99999 |
| row3 | 10 | B:9999999999 |

I want to creat column2 from column1,
So I've written the code to assign new column as below.

`df2=df.assign(column2=lambda x : "B:" +"9"*x.column1.astype('int'))`

But only result I can get is

> ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) ->dtype('<U21')

Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["column2"] = "B:" + df["column1"] * pd.Series(
    ["9"] * len(df), index=df.index
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      column1       column2
row1        2          B:99
row2        5       B:99999
row3       10  B:9999999999
```

---

Or:

```py
df["column2"] = "9"
df["column2"] = "B:" + df["column1"] * df["column2"]
```

Comment: Sorry for late check, Thx !!